# Firebase is not allowing to delete all users

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

No matter what i tried, I could not delete users from Firebase Cloud Function.

I can list all users, but `deleteUsers` function always return error for no reason.

*Try number 1 :*

```
 exports.removeUsers = functions.https.onRequest(async(request, response) => {


      cors(request, response, async () => {

                  const allUsers = await auth.listUsers();
                  const allUsersUID = allUsers.users.map((user) => user.uid);
                  return auth.deleteUsers(allUsersUID).then(() => response.send("deleted"));
   

     });
 });
```

*Try number 2 no `async` inside* :

```
              //list 1000 users
              var nextPageToken;
              const usersToDelete = [];
              admin.auth().listUsers(1000, nextPageToken).then(function(listUsersResult) {
                    listUsersResult.users.forEach(function(userRecord) {
                      var userID = userRecord.toJSON().uid;
                      usersToDelete.push(userID);
                    });
                    return;
              }).then(() => {
               console.log(usersToDelete.length);
               return admin.auth().deleteUsers(usersToDelete);
              }).catch(function(error) {
                          console.log('Error listing users:', error);
              });
```

Both functions **will** list all users (880), but will show error on functions logs saying :

> Error listing users: TypeError: admin.auth(...).deleteUsers is not a function

Not sure why this is not a function, start to think Google just don't like you deleting all of your users.

Comment: The delete users method returns a list of failures for the users that were unable to be deleted. Is this what you want to do? https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#delete_multiple_users

Comment: thank you, it return something when it works, i get an error that its not a function. I obviously read this API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the version of the Admin SDK you are using, as `deleteUsers` was added relatively recently in [version 8.12](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/admin/node#version_8120_-_06_may_2020) of the Node.js SDK.

Comment: thanks, running 'firebase tools --version',  will show 8.2 since i updated it lately. Also getUsers works, so its probably not the problem since they add both in the same time. I just can not figure this out.

Comment: Hmm... weird. Let me know if you ever figure it out.

Comment: it was the version. i had the right one but only after update it worked.